# How is Visual Studio 2010 performance compared to 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, performance, visual-studio-2010

Thinking about installing Visual Studio on my Asus eee 1000HE. Since it is not a very powerful machine, I am wondering if I should install 2008 or the new 2010. Looks like there has been a lot of changes done to the UI, etc. Does that mean that it now runs smoother as well? Or is it actually heavier to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that VS2010 is currently only available as a CTP release, I'd install VS2008.

Once VS2010 is fully released, without debug information and with optimizations enabled, ask this question and consider using it. For the moment, if you have 2008, use it. I doubt 2010 will be faster on your 'slow' hardware.

Comment: It's actually a beta right now, which (at least for MS) is a step beyond CTP.  Agree that it's still not ready for everyday usage.

Comment: I went here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products/2010/default.mspx and it says CTP, but as you say - that means "still not ready", even if I could "reap the rewards of tomorrow's efficiency today" <pass the sick bag> :)

Comment: VS2008 boots up in under a second from my solid state drive, while VS2010 sets there at the splash screen for a good 10 seconds before loading.

Answer (score 5):

2010 is much slower on older machines in my opinion.  I am running it currently on a Dell 700m with 512MB of RAM and while it does run, it feels sluggish and significantly slower than Visual Studio 2008.  (Remember that it is a beta though, I am sure that performance tweaks are forthcoming)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit more difficult to judge the performance differences since you **are** running it in a virtual machine at this time (no stand alone beta out yet).

**Edit**: If I am incorrect on the inability to run it outside of a virtual machine I apologize and stand corrected.

Comment: It's available as a standalone beta.

Comment: Last time I had ever looked into it, it was only as a VPC. Now that I know it's stand alone I'll be able to give it another look. Thanks for the heads up Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that it now runs smoother as well? Or is it actually heavier to run?

This is an old post, I know, but I just had to chime in and laugh: *lol*

I had a pretty decent overclocked Wolfdale-based machine I built for gaming. Fast enough for virtually everything I need to do on a computer, except for editing text files in Visual Studio 2010. Just scrolling up and down in a C# file maxed out one of my cores. No joke.

So I upgraded to the new Sandy Bridge 32nm CPUs (3.3GHz, unlocked model) in an enthusiast motherboard, with 8GB of Corsair RAM, and scrolling moving the cursor around in a text buffer in VS2010 is using 30% of the CPU (that's right, it's using multiple cores). This is with no plugins and outlining turned off.

Vim in the same file, doing pretty much anything I can think of, shows 0% CPU usage, always.

VS2010's editor performance is absolutely shameful. There's  no other word for it.

Comment: I have to lol @ you for comparing it to vim. Why even bother doing that?

Comment: @sylvannar: Vim is the editor I use outside of Visual Studio. Cursoring-around a buffer in Visual Studio maxes a core. Doing the same in Vim uses 0% CPU.

Comment: Vim is a general purpose text editor. VS is an IDE. They are apples and oranges.

Comment: @sylvannar: my Vim *is* an IDE; I've integrated project management, source control, debugging, code inspection, etc. into it, just like any other IDE. But that's beside the point. I'm comparing the *editor* in Visual Studio to another editor, performing the same action (scrolling around a buffer). The only reason I mention Vim is to show that scrolling around a buffer of text is not an intrinsically expensive operation; there's no reason for it to max out a freakin' CPU core in VS.